# Apple Swift: how to get current seconds in 1/100 or 1/1000?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nscalendar

```
func updateTime() {
    var date = NSDate()
    var calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    var components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: date)
    var hour = components.hour
    var minutes = components.minute
    var seconds = components.second
    counterLabel.text = "\(seconds)"

    var myIndicator = counterLabel.text?.toInt()

    if myIndicator! % 2 == 0 {
        // do this
    } else {
       // do that
    }
}
```

I'd like to know how I can change this code so I get 1/10 or 1/100 or 1/1000 of a second to display in counterlabel.text.
Just can't figure it out... thanks!

Comment: Note that all the variables in your code can actually be defined as constants (`let`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a calendar unit for nanoseconds:

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitNanosecond, fromDate: date)
let nanoSeconds = components.nanosecond
```

Update for Swift 3

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = NSCalendar.current
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.nanosecond], from: date)
let nanoSeconds = components.nanosecond
```

This gives the fractional part of the seconds in units of  10<sup>-9</sup> seconds. 
For milliseconds, just divide this value by 10<sup>6</sup>:

```
let milliSeconds = nanoSeconds / 1_000_000
```

Alternatively, if you just want to *display* the fractional
seconds, use a `NSDateFormatter` and the `SSS` format. Example:

```
let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
fmt.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss.SSS"
counterLabel.text = fmt.stringFromDate(date)
```

Update for Swift 3

```
let fmt = DateFormatter()
fmt.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss.SSS"
counterLabel.text = fmt.stringFromDate(date)
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin. Worked like a charm!